# aiohttp async with stripe Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am learning Django and I am trying to use aiohttp but I am unable to figure how can I use it with stripe API calls.

This is my code:

```
class ListCardSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

pm = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

class Meta:
    model = Bill
    fields = ["pm"]

def get_pm(self, obj):
    stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_API_KEY
    cost = stripe.Customer.retrieve(customer_id)
    pm = stripe.Customer.list_payment_methods(
        customer_id, type="card"
    )
    return pm
```

I am new to Django any help will be appreciated. I am trying to convert my functions into async await.

Comment: Not possible with Stripe Python library. Feature request since 2017: [stripe/stripe-python#327](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python/issues/327)

Answer (score 1):

I've created a pure async stripe client for Python: https://github.com/bhch/async-stripe/.

Every network call is an async coroutine.

Usage:

```
from async_stripe import stripe

stripe.api_key = '<your stripe api key>'

async def get_pm(self, obj):
    cost = await stripe.Customer.retrieve(customer_id)
    pm = await stripe.Customer.list_payment_methods(
        customer_id, type="card"
    )
    return pm
```